# Find out last password modified timestamp of an user in Cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, passwords, cql

I am a student, and I am trying to find the details on how to get the last password modified date and time for a user in cql. Please help me with the query to find out the last password modified date and time of the user1 ID in Cassandra DB.

Thanks,
Tina

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use the `writetime()` function on the `salted_hash` column on the `system_auth.roles` table:

```
> SELECT role,writetime(salted_hash)
  FROm roles WHERE role='aaron';

 role  | writetime(salted_hash)
-------+------------------------
 aaron |       1698686437684000

(1 rows)
```

When this writetime is [converted](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to a date/time, I can see that I changed my password on Monday, October 30, 2023 at 12:20:37.684 PM GMT-05:00.